# Apple TV Developer Kit Differences

Tags: tvos

Does anyone know how the Apple TV Developer kit differs from the commercial one?

For instance, The App Store doesn't seem to be available on the Dev Kit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `13T396` "GM"  tvOS build has been available since October 21st.

However, on October 29th the "release version" of tvOS was added to the Apple website. Annoyingly, this is also marked as build `13T396`.

The tvOS App Store showed up on my Dev Kit after downloading and restoring the release build. I had tried restoring the "GM" several times, after the App Store went live, with no success.

Make sure to download the new bits released on 10/29, and use that build (`13T396`) rather than the GM (`13T396`).

[image: tvOS release version]

Once the Release build has been installed, your dev kit will be at "absolute parity" with retail Apple TVs.

> Yes - there will be an update that brings the dev kit OS to absolute parity with shipping units.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18615

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now :) Oh how big of a difference a few hours make.

Answer (score 2):

According to this post on the developer forums, the App Store is not available yet. Sometime in the future (Unknown at the moment) the dev kit will be able to update "to absolute parity with shipping units."

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18615